# undefined reference _cblas_dgemm in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, lapack

I have installed the shark machine learning library on Ubuntu and linked it with `libshark_debug.so` and `liblapack_atlas.so`. `liblapack_atlas.so` was in `libatlas-base-dev` package. Now I want to do the same on Mac OS X, but I can not find `liblapack_atlas.so`. Linker stops with this error:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_cblas_dgemm", reference from:
shark::blas::binding::gemm()
```

Which package should I install (using brew for instance) to be able to link my C++ program with `liblapack_atlas.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X already provides a `.dylib` for BLAS, on my system it's located at `/usr/lib/libblas.dylib` but YMMV for location. A quick check of it's exported symbols gives me this:

```
nm -gU /usr/lib/libblas.dylib | grep dgemm
...
000000000016e454 T _cblas_dgemm
```

Also provides a `liblapack` library as well, which is at: `/usr/lib/liblapack.dylib`.

Comment: How to use it?
g++ myprogram.cpp still gives an error

Comment: You'll need to add a library link command pointing to it, but it's probably worth while opening a new question if you're stuck.